# Unity C# – Accessing subclass properties from variable defined as derived class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write an xml parser to take some data in a game and build out objects for me. Right now I want to go through the nodes and build out different config objects based on the node/attributes.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in actionList) {
  ActionConfig config;
  if (some checks determine action is "Fire") {
    config = new FireActionConfig();
    config.speed = (float)node.Attributes["speed"].Value;
  }
  // do something with config
}
```

The error I get is "ActionConfig does not contain a definition for speed...". I tried casting config as FireActionConfig even though it's already defined as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (XmlNode node in actionList) {
    ActionConfig config;
    if (some checks determine action is "Fire") {

        FireActionConfig fireConfig = new FireActionConfig();
        fireConfig.speed = Single.Parse( node.Attributes["speed"].Value );
        config = fireConfig;
    }

    // do something with config
  }
```

Comment: or in-line casting, `((FireActionConfig)config).speed = ...`